# Symfony solr bundle 2.8 +

Tags: php, solr, symfony

I started to get data from `solr` with `curl` but this is not the `symfony` way and I want to change that before is "to late".

There is most popular `nelmio solr bundle` (this is info I found from googling) i also found some other bundles, but wanted to pleased you to help me in choosing `nelmio` or suggest some better bundle that is fully support also and `symfony 3.0`

Comment: There is also the  wpsolr-search-engine plugin for Wordpress which could be adapted for use in any PHP project.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using curl with Symfony.  Quite a common practice.  If usig a another bundle makes your life easier then great.  If your existing code does the job then don't worry about it.

Comment: I also would appreciate any answer. Also: would SolrBundle be a good choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: Using NelmioSolarBundle and floriansemm/SolrBundle have very different use cases.

NelmioSolrBundle is just a symfony integration of the solarium library, which is nothing more than a wrapper around those direct curl requests.

The SolrBundle by floriansemm integrates solr deeper into the framework by making annotations available to declare which entity fields i.e. are stored or indexed in solr (done via dynamic fields). I found the options using normal schema.xml definitions are way more powerful since not everything is available there.

In my current project i first tried using SolrBundle but ran into some limitations which led me to switch to NelmioSolariumBundle. (so my solr config and schema are maintained directly in the solr and not through annotations and so on)
Once you get used to the solarium library (http://www.solarium-project.org/) the nelmio bundle works fine but in the end it's nothing more than a fancy way of executing those curl requests.

So if your implementation works, keep using it.

Hope this helps.